# What java application design to choose when needing a mix of javafx (3rd party libs) and spring mvc rest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, javafx, libraries

I have to create a java application. I'm not new to programming, but relatively new to java. So I have a question about application design.

**Situation:** I have to use a 3rd party library, containing some so-called "toolkits". One toolkit within this lib uses javafx. My application, which is mainly depends on this lib should ask the lib for data, receives it and than I want to populate this data via spring rest or sockets or sth. else.

**I already tried** a spring mvc app, that starts the javafx-application within another thread and each call from the mvc rest controller, calls the javafx with "runLater".

**The problem is**, that when this lib want's to show a javafx gui, it will be displayed and the buttons are clickable (gui doesn't freeze), but the gui (especially the listview) might won't get updated. I can't debug it because the listview depends on a hardware-input-event (usb). Maybe I can't mix javafx that way or I wrongly accessed this thread. Or maybe I did everything correctly and the problem might not be the mix of javafx and spring mvc rest. Maybe it's complety incompatible. I don't know by myself.

So that way, I ask for an application design that fits my needs. It would be great, when somebody could explain my, how I could move the complete 3rd party lib to a javafx thread, that I can safely call from spring mvc rest controller. So that in result the gui pops up (this already works), but does its things right (what might not work). But any other application designs (extra services, multiple jvms / jars / processes / sockets) etc. are appreciated. But since java is relatively new to me, I have to ask the pros out there. But this 3rd party lib is essential and only given as jar.

I have no influence to the javafx part and I am not allowed to publish some code of this 3rd party lib. But these "toolkits" within this 3rd party lib are mostly declared as "static" - if that helps.

If you want to go on with the approach "spring mvc rest and javafx", I could post the code of main() (Application.java)

So much thanks in advance. Hope, you don't downvote, though it's an more general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that it is possible to use Spring MVC Rest and call some javafx libraries, but the usage of Threads and Plattform.runLater() is recommended to avoid freezing the gui (or even worse).

My special problem about not updating the listview of the 3rd party javafx lib was caused by a library not being loaded from intellij. The 3rd party lib didn't throw any exceptions so I thought, it was a threading problem.

So far, everything works as expected. And I learned some rules regarding java, javafx, concurrency (e.g. CountdownLatch) and spring. Maybe, that's a starting point for someone else.

Happy coding!